# How to create a dataframe using spark java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

I need to create a data frame in my test.
I tried the code below:

```java
StructType structType = new StructType();
structType = structType.add("A", DataTypes.StringType, false);
structType = structType.add("B", DataTypes.StringType, false);

List<String> nums = new ArrayList<String>();
nums.add("value1");
nums.add("value2");

Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(nums, structType);
```

The expected result is :

```
 +------+------+
 |A     |B     |
 +------+------+
 |value1|value2|
 +------+------+
```

But it is not accepted. How do I initiate a data frame/Dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Spark 3.0 and before, `SparkSession` instances don't have a method to create dataframe from list of Objects and a `StructType`.

However, there is a method that can build dataframe from list of rows and a `StructType`. So to make your code work, you have to change your `nums` type from `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Row>`. You can do that using [RowFactory](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/RowFactory.html):

```java
// imports
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;

// code
StructType structType = new StructType();
structType = structType.add("A", DataTypes.StringType, false);
structType = structType.add("B", DataTypes.StringType, false);

List<Row> nums = new ArrayList<Row>();
nums.add(RowFactory.create("value1", "value2"));

Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(nums, structType);

// result
// +------+------+
// |A     |B     |
// +------+------+
// |value1|value2|
// +------+------+
```

If you want to add more rows to your dataframe, just add other rows:

```java
// code
...

List<Row> nums = new ArrayList<Row>();
nums.add(RowFactory.create("value1", "value2"));
nums.add(RowFactory.create("value3", "value4"));

Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(nums, structType);

// result
// +------+------+
// |A     |B     |
// +------+------+
// |value1|value2|
// |value3|value4|
// +------+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is the cleaner way of doing things.

Step 1: Create a bean class for your custom class. Make sure you have public getter, setter and all args constructor and the class should implement serializable

```
public class StringWrapper implements Serializable {
  private String key;
  private String value;

  public StringWrapper(String key, String value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Step 2: Generate data

```
List<StringWrapper> nums = new ArrayList<>();
nums.add(new StringWrapper("value1", "value2"));
```

Step 3: Convert it to RDD

```
JavaRDD<StringWrapper> rdd = javaSparkContext.parallelize(nums);
```

Step 4: Convert it to dataset

```
sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd, StringWrapper.class).show(false);
```

Step 5 : See results

```
+------+------+
|key   |value |
+------+------+
|value1|value2|
+------+------+
```

Comment: thank you but I have to initiate a df without any another class, there is no another solution please?(i edited my post with the expected result)

Comment: updated the answer ... you either create a bean class or you create a custom struct ... I feel bean class is lot cleaner